PrimeFaces chart changes between 12 and 14
I am trying to upgrade from PrimeFaces 12 to PrimeFaces 14. Chart data is deprecated in version 12, inside my bar chart model I am using chart data. Any suggestions with rewrite in this scenario.
I am trying to use bardata and trying to rewrite my model class. I want to see if this is a better approach before proceeding. Also, would like to know any easy and reliable solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't fully understand what you mean with "chart data", but what you should do when upgrading PrimeFaces is follow the migration guides. It shows you all breaking changes between each version.
For the data model you can simply check the documentation. Check chart, not charts as it is deprecated since 15.
See also:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/10870
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/docs/migrationguide/15_0_0.md
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml


I have couple of issues that I am facing while upgrading primefaces version from 12 to 14.                           1. Expression does not match the following pattern @widgetVar(var).   2. Cannot invoke getclientId(Context) because target is null                                          I am not sure why this is happening.

Looks like this is an issue from primefaces.
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12470

That issue is unrelated to your question. There will probably be more issues, as it's a huge library.
